# how can i programmatically modify the url of a sitemap node in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to do this :

```
  SiteMapNode node = (e.Item.DataItem as SiteMapNode);
  node.Url = "/" + PartnerName + "/" + routingValue.First().Key + "/" + FileName;
```

but an error occurred saying the node url cannot be modified it is read only